# How to dump from file in server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Rails App with two model

post.rb

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    #  id                  :integer(11)    not null, primary key
    #  title            :text   
    #  body          :text  
 end
```

and post_dumps.rb

```
   class PostDump < ActiveRecord::Base
      #  id                  :integer(11)    not null, primary key
      #  dupm_file           
      mount_uploader :dupm_file, DumpUploader # sql file was uploaded
    end
```

How to create method like this in  PostDumpsController

```
class PostDumpsController < ApplicationController
  def update_posts_from_dump
    @dump = PostDump.find(params[:id])
    Post.destroy_all
    # run from root user in server
    mysql -uroot -ppasswrord production_bd < @dump.dupm_file_url
  end
end
```

Comment: That looks like a crazy dangerous thing to be doing. If you really have no other option, look at the `system` command.

Comment: @tadman if I were to write a poem on that topic, I would name it “Two backticks as the answer to how to shoot your own leg.”

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't you use rake task for anything like this. Use a location on
>   your server where from where you can dump data into the database. You
>   can even schedule it using cronjob.

Note: I am unaware of the exact requirement, why you want to do this but if something of this sort is to be done then above mentioned is a better approach.